# why is an annulus close to it's boundary when it's boundary curves are close?

Tags: general-topology, plane-curves

This is the motivating question for the rather vague question here: [when is the region bounded by a Jordan curve "skinny"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401933/when-is-the-region-bounded-by-a-jordan-curve-skinny)

Suppose we are given two Jordan curves in the plane, one inside the other and each contained in an epsilon neighborhood of the other. How can we conclude that the annular region between the two curves is itself contained in the two epsilon neighborhoods of the original curves?

Note: by epsilon neighborhood of a curve I mean the set of all points which lie within a distance epsilon from some point in the image of the curve.

---

Follow up: Since the statement above is false (see Hagen's answer) we might ask whether it is true if we assume point-wise closeness of chosen parametrizations of the curves.  This is answered in the affirmative by user7...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can't. Consider an arbitrarily large closed disk. At two points of its circumference let two thin strips emerge that first wind araound back and forth very close to the disk boundary and then meet. The contour arount this figure consists of two Jordan curves making a counterexample.

[image]

Comment: You are right!  Maybe I should have required that the parametrizations be pointwise close.

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be very similar to the counterexample that Hagen von Eitzen described in words, but I'm not entirely sure. So here's a [fooplot](http://fooplot.com/plot/708g58yynq).

If you assume that $|f(\theta)-g(\theta)|< 2\epsilon$ for all $\theta$ (where $f$ and $g$ are the two curves), then the conclusion is true. Indeed, suppose that the disk $|z-a|< \epsilon$ is contained in the annulus. We may and do assume $a=0$. Then the winding numbers of $f$ and $g$ around $0$ are different: one is $0$, the other is $1$. On the other hand, I claim that $$f_t(\theta)=(1-t)f(\theta)+tg(\theta)$$
is a homotopy between $f$ and $g$ in $\mathbb R^2\setminus \{0\}$.

Indeed, if $f_t(\theta)=0$ for some $\theta$, then the points $f(\theta),0, g(\theta)$ lie on a line, in the order listed. Hence $|f(\theta)-g(\theta)|=|f(\theta)|+|g(\theta)|\ge 2\epsilon$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks!  What do you think about requiring the parametrizations to be pointwise close?  If that is a better question would it be bad form to edit the original post?

Comment: Ahz, your example is simpler than mine (which is already a simplification of my original thought). The "inner branch" of my red curve is indeed superfluous.

Comment: @Rimbaud I answered the follow-up question. I guess since the answer is here already, you can just add a follow-up after `---` (but do keep the original question as well).

Comment: How elegant! Thanks so much for all your help.